# Help me with understanding root objects

Tags: equation-solving, functions, slot

I solved an polynomial equation of degree 20 and got root objects as solutions. I cannot understand how to match such output to any standard analytic form. After studying `Function` and `Root`, I still can't understand how use the solutions, so please can anyone help me to understand the results I am getting?

```
First[Solve[(x + 1)^20 + x - 2 == 0, x]]
```

> `{x -> Root[-1 + 21 #1 + 190 #1^2 + 1140 #1^3 + 4845 #1^4 + 
>        15504 #1^5 + 38760 #1^6 + 77520 #1^7 + 125970 #1^8 + 
>        167960 #1^9 + 184756 #1^10 + 167960 #1^11 + 125970 #1^12 + 
>        77520 #1^13 + 38760 #1^14 + 15504 #1^15 + 4845 #1^16 + 
>        1140 #1^17 + 190 #1^18 + 20 #1^19 + #1^20 &, 1]}`

I need the total meaning of such output to apply it in real calculations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eqn = (x + 1)^20 + x - 2 == 0;

(sol = First@Solve[eqn, x]) // InputForm

(* {x -> Root[-1 + 21*#1 + 190*#1^2 + 
     1140*#1^3 + 4845*#1^4 + 
     15504*#1^5 + 38760*#1^6 + 
     77520*#1^7 + 125970*#1^8 + 
     167960*#1^9 + 184756*#1^10 + 
     167960*#1^11 + 125970*#1^12 + 
     77520*#1^13 + 38760*#1^14 + 
     15504*#1^15 + 4845*#1^16 + 
     1140*#1^17 + 190*#1^18 + 
     20*#1^19 + #1^20 & , 1, 0]} *)
```

The **exact** solutions of the equation are [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. Because the polynomial is of high order, the roots cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. `Root` objects can be used the same as any solution. For example, to verify that the solution satisfies the original equation:

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Use [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) to get the approximate numeric value of a `Root` object

```
sol // N // InputForm

(* {x -> -2.0727396474052435} *)
```

For a much smaller order polynomial the `Root` objects can be converted to radicals.

```
eqn2 = (x + 1)^3 + x - 2 == 0;

(sol2 = First@Solve[eqn2, x]) // InputForm

(* {x -> Root[-1 + 4*#1 + 3*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 1, 0]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn2 /. sol2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Converting to radicals

```
sol2r = sol2 // ToRadicals

(* {x -> -1 - (2/(3 (27 + Sqrt[741])))^(1/3) + 
   (1/2 (27 + Sqrt[741]))^(1/3)/3^(2/3)} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn2 /. sol2r // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The numeric value is

```
sol2 // N

{x -> 0.213412}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon for explaining this